# AV Receiver playing music using RCA Analog input (AUX) from Mobile 3.5 mm stereo source

Tags: audio, power-amplifier, preamp

I have a pioneer AV Receiver VSX-832-K with RCA AUX INPUT "input (Sensitive/Impendency  ) 200mv/47K ohm"

issue :
when i am trying to play music from mobile using 3.5 mm headphone jack using RCA cable connected to AVR, music is coming with low volume with distorted audio like imbalance of base/treble/loudness/voice

if i use source from Blu-ray RCA out put, sound quality is perfectly fine
2.0vms (1khz,0DB),600Ohm  RCA Jack L/R

Query : what circuit can be used to convert mobile 3.5 jack out put compatible with AVR RCA input to have better sound quality, i observed that cheap audio system is playing audio without much noticeable distorted audio but it is really bad if i hook it to my AVR VSX-832-K

https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/jack-headset-spec
Mobile 3.5 mm head phone jack specification

Maximum output voltage drive    150mV   >= 150mV on 32 ohm

Headset Speaker Impedance Level Device Support  Notes
Low Threshold Detection : Headphone (low) < 1 Kohm
High Threshold Detection :Line In (high) > 5 Kohm

Comment: This site isn't a support group for every branded electronic amplifier ever made.

Comment: i intended to ask a generic question to the experts what kind of electronics circuit to engage considering the data i shared, i designed few preamp and engaged but that did not improve the quality as much. I am not looking at the AVR brand but this generic incompatibility issue  i observed across AVR from different brands

Comment: Well aside from any normal audio preamp, guess you need to build a single channel preamp yourself. I can not find any special 3,5mm jack in, RCA out ones. But I never had any trouble feeding signals into my stereo-amp's pre-amplifier stage. All values you need are around in the net, Wikipedia at least showed everything I needed to know. levels and impedance's...